# Added UIViewController in UIView giving trouble

Tags: iphone

I want to add a UIViewController class to an existing class as a subview, so i used the following code.

```
myEventsView = [[EventNameViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"EventNameViewController" bundle:nil];
[myEventsView.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 39, 320, 400)];
[self.view addSubview:myEventsView.view];
```

It is added successfully but the problem is with button actions, those actions which have to navigate to other view controllers are not working. Those action methods are called, but action not performed, not getting why so, please guide for the above.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: EventNameViewController is a sub class of UINavigationController?

Comment: @Ishank EventNameViewController is a UIViewController class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
myEventsView = [[EventNameViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"EventNameViewController" bundle:nil];
[myEventsView.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 39, 320, 400)];
[myEventsView willMoveToParentViewController:self];
[self.view addSubview:myEventsView.view];
[self addChildViewController:myEventsView];
[myEventsView didMoveToParentViewController:self];
```

Comment: @iPhone The idea is straight forward, when you are adding a viewController to a viewController you need to add it as a childViewController so that childViewController will get properly initialized. More read [Custom Container View Controllers](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers.html)

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/AboutViewControllers/AboutViewControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH112-SW12):

> Each custom view controller object you create is responsible for managing all of the views in a single view hierarchy.

What you are trying to do is to add one viewcontroller's view as a subview of another viewcontroller's view, hence mixing two view hierarchies. That will cause you problems as you have already experienced. Have a look at Carbon Emitter's [Abusing UIViewCtrollers](http://blog.carbonfive.com/2011/03/09/abusing-uiviewcontrollers/) article, it gives a thorough explanation and an alternative.

**Update**

As suggested in the correct answer above, there exists a way to make one UIViewController act as a container for another. From [Implementing a Container View Controller](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) (UIViewController Class Reference):

> A custom UIViewController subclass can also act as a container view controller. A container view controller manages the presentation of content of other view controllers it owns, also known as its child view controllers. A child’s view can be presented as-is or in conjunction with views owned by the container view controller.

However, this is an iOS  >= 5 feature, so my answer will remain correct for applications running iOS versions < 5.

Answer (score -1):

Muncken is right. You cannot add `myEventsView.view` as a subview to `self.view`, since `myEventsView.view` is controlled by its own view controller.
What you probably wanted to do is to add just an new view (that is **not** controlled by another view controller) as a subview to `self.view`. So, why don't you just instantiate such a view without a new view controller?